# Is it possible to change Roving rn-171 WiFly module device configuration through SPI and not UART?

Tags: pic, spi, uart, wifi, wifly

I am interfacing rn-171 WiFly module with PIC18F27J13 chip.
I want to save both USARTs available on the PIC for other purposes.

I am wondering whether I can just connect the Roving SPI pins to the PIC uc,
to bring or activate WiFly command mode by sending $$$ to WiFly over SPI without any need to connect UART pins.

If so, what could be a reasonable simple schematic for the pins connection.
Thanks

Comment: You can use a SPI to UART chip: SC16IS750. In fact, sparkfun uses it for a Roving Network device as well.

Comment: It does *have* an SPI connection, but it looks like RN doesn't want you to use it. You'll need to contact them.

Answer (score 1):

Try asking the vendor support, there is SPI firmware for RN171 module available on request.

With this firmware on the WiFly you can use SPI directly instead of UART.

The documentation for SPI (e.g. pins, configuration commands) is not avilable on the www AFAIK, so you need to contact support to get this.